# Filter list of dicts in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Series containing a list of dictionaries. I'd like to filter out dictionaries based on a condition. Here's some sample data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'d': [[{'br': 1, 'ba': 1, 'r': 100},
                         {'ba': 1, 'r': 80},
                         {'br': 2, 'ba': 1, 'r': 150},
                         {'br': 1, 'ba': 1, 'r': 90}],

                        [{'br': 1, 'ba': 1, 'r': 100},
                         {'ba': 1, 'r': 80},
                         {'br': 2, 'ba': 1, 'r': 150}]],

                   'id': ['xxas', 'yxas'],

                   'name': ['A', 'B']

                 })
```

I'd like to remove all the `dicts` with `value` of key `r` `> 100`. Expected output:

```
dff = pd.DataFrame({'d': [[{'br': 1, 'ba': 1, 'r': 100},
                           {'ba': 1, 'r': 80},
                           {'br': 1, 'ba': 1, 'r': 90}],

                          [{'br': 1, 'ba': 1, 'r': 100},
                           {'ba': 1, 'r': 80}]],
    
                       'id': ['xxas', 'yxas'],
    
                       'name': ['A', 'B']
    
                     })
```

Comment: Your expected output contains elements with `r <= 100`, not `r > 100` as you said.

Comment: @baileythegreen correct, I'd like to keep `r <= 100` and filter out `r > 100`.

Comment: I assume 'name' consists of strings, otherwise, it throws a syntax error,

Answer (score 2):

You could use a list comprehension to filter:

```
df['d'] = [[d for d in row  if d['r']<=100] for row in df['d']]
```

Output:

```
                                                   d    id name
0  [{'br': 1, 'ba': 1, 'r': 100}, {'ba': 1, 'r': ...  xxas    A
1  [{'br': 1, 'ba': 1, 'r': 100}, {'ba': 1, 'r': ...  yxas    B
```

Comment: This is very slick.  I don't get where row comes from.

Comment: @jch thanks; `row` is the iteration variable of the outer loop: `for row in df['d']...`